# Barebones 328p, 2xAA vs 3xAA, which will last longer?

Tags: atmega328, battery

So im just running a 328p at 8mhz with the internal oscillator. Datasheet says 1.8 to 5.5v is voltage range.

Will 3xAA in series (~4.5v) last longer than 2xAA in series (~3v), assuming all batteries have the same capacity, theoretically each option should have the same mAh but does the difference in voltage affect things ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, running at a higher voltage will consume more current.  In the datasheet you have this nice graph:

[image: ATMega328P Voltage vs Current]

I have highlighted the two voltages at 8MHz for you. At 4.5V you would typically be using about 4.7mA.  At 3V you would be using around 2.8mA.  That's not taking into account anything else in your circuit of course - just the ATMega itself.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, yes its just the atmega im talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Majenko's answer is correct, however he (or both of you) are assuming that the processor clock is running. When it runs, a processor cycle at a higher voltage will use more current. However when in power-down sleep mode the clock stops, and consumption is much lower. If you don't need the watchdog timer (for example, a switch closure activates the processor) then the difference will be negligible. Indeed, the current consumption is around 100 nA.

[image: Current usage - no watchdog timer]

If you need the watchdog to periodically wake you, then the difference will be about 2 µA (that's a lot less than 2.8 mA).

[image: Current usage - watchdog timer]

These are quoted at room temperature - around 25°C.

---

I would be concerned about 2 x AA batteries. Their nominal voltage might be 3V, but their actual voltage (say, if they are NiMh batteries) might be closer to 2.4V, and that is the minimal amount for running at 8 MHz.

With 3 x AA batteries you are much more safely in range for the voltage requirements, particularly if you have some peripherals that might drain power, and thus lower the voltage.

---

Other discussions about low-power considerations at http://www.gammon.com.au/power.